# Nexus 4 red light of death. Unable to fix it (tried two possible solutions)

Tags: battery, nexus-4, charging

Using a 3-year Nexus 4, I started yesterday to suffer the red light of death issue.

Firtsly, I open the unit, disconected and conected the battery, following the directions of:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWABgDHvfx0

It did not work, so I tried to power off the device through the bootloader menu:
https://support.google.com/nexus/troubleshooter/3337561?hl=en#ts=3337943

The battery icon appeared on my screen, I waited for nearly two hours but, when trying to turn it on, the red light appared again and the device did not turn on.

What am I doing wrong? Any tip is welcome.